# Unread chat messages in mysql and php

Tags: mysql

In my mysql database I have data about unread messages and their recipients. 
So I make a Mysql query to fugure who and how much messages have.

```
SELECT author FROM messages WHERE recipient='$_SESSION[id]' and viewed=0
```

I get result which looks like:

```
49 49 49 49 49 12 12 56
```

How to construct this array to get the final output result like this:

```
You have 5 messages from member 49, 2 from member 12, 1 from member 56?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT author, count(author) as 'nr' 
FROM messages WHERE recipient='$_SESSION[id]' 
       and viewed=0 
GROUP BY author
```

this will give you 2 columns each row: the first is the author id and the second (labeled 'nr', change it as you wish) the number of unread messages from that author.

Please note: your code may be vulnerable to sql injection. Take extra care and possibly learn about prepared statements.

PS: note that `$_SESSION[id]` raises a warning because `id` is an undefined constant, as it is now. remember to put quotes around it.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun...

```
SELECT REPLACE(
         CONCAT("You have ",
           GROUP_CONCAT(
             CONCAT(" ",ttl," messages from member ",author) 
           ORDER BY ttl DESC)
          ),"  "," ")a
 FROM 
    (
       SELECT author,COUNT(*) ttl   
         FROM messages 
        WHERE recipient = 1 
          AND viewed = 0
        GROUP 
           BY author
    ) x;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the result based on the array you have already.

```
$results = array(49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 12, 12, 56);

$messages = array();

foreach($results as $author) {
    isset($messages[$author]) ? $messages[$author]++ : $messages[$author] = 1;
}

$display = '';

$first = true;
foreach($messages as $author => $count) {
    if($first) {
        $display .= sprintf('You have %s messages from %s', $count, $author);
    }
    else {
        $display .= sprintf(', %s messages from %s', $count, $author);
        $first = false;
    }
}

echo $display;
```

Comment: My forgotten twin, huh? :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$messages = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $sendser = $result['sender'];
    if (!isset($messages['sender'])) {
        $messages['sender'] = array();
    }
    $messages['sender'][] = $result;
}

// Here you have your messages as entities sorted by sender in a map
// ...

if (count($messages) != 0) {
    $notice = "You have ";
    $firstSender = true;
    foreach ($messages as $sender=>$msgsFromSender) {
        $pattern = ($firstSender) ? "%d messages from member %s" : ", %s from member %s";
        $notice .= sprintf($pattern, count($msgsFromSender), $sender);
    }
    $notice .= ".";
}

// ...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT author,count(author) 
from messages WHERE recipient='$_SESSION[id]' and viewed=0 
GROUP by author
```

Comment: Oh yes, I took that bit from OP's code. You've been much faster anyway with the correct reply! ;-)